# How can I visually explain M of N encryption (Shamir Key Sharing)?

Tags: encryption

I'm trying to find a simple way to explain M of N keys to end users, where 2 keys would unlock something.

So far, all I found was this complex example where the key threshold was 1 (just one key of any lock will unlock this):

[image: Photo of physical locks implementing solution with key treshold of one.]

[Larger version here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2qis.jpg)

Lacking any commonly accepted illustration, or image, is there any visual way to express M of N keys (Shamir Secret Sharing)?

Comment: I would suggest researching visual secret sharing, there you can find examples which are really easy to grasp without any numbers at all. $2,2$ VSS schemes are quite simple, and then show how to go to more general $k,n$ schemes. You probably won't find a proper illustration for arbitrary $2,n$ schemes.

Comment: If you want other examples then I link some in an [answer on the puzzling stack](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/379/228).

Answer (score 5):

I've used the following a number of times in lectures, and it always goes over well with a technical audience.

1. I start by asking them *How many points do we need to uniquely define a line?* The answer I get back is always *2*.
2. Next I ask *If I give you a single point in the X,Y plane, how many lines can you draw through that point?* The answer I always get back is *infinite*.
3. Finally I say, *Let's consider I have some secret (usually I use 42 for the obvious reason) and I want to share this secret with many people so that any two of them could get together and reconstruct the secret.*

At this point, depending on the audience, I will either ask how I could accomplish this, hoping they get the idea to somehow encode 42 into the line (e.g., as the y intercept). Or, I will just tell them how it works.

All of this can be shown visually, which I would try to add pictures here, but I don't have time at the moment.

For even non-mathematical audiences, if I start with #2 above (draw a point on the board or in a slide and ask how many straight lines can be drawn that pass through this point), it works well. Then I move to #1, then #3.

Answer (score 2):

> I think I misinterpreted the question. This answer describes how to visualise the cryptographic working of threshold schemes. It is not really good for visualising the *idea* of these kinds of schemes to laymen.

I think the best way to explain Shamir secret sharing is by using graphs. Most readers will have a basic understanding of low-order polynomials, so you could do something like this:

## Share creation

Let us explain a simplified form of Shamir Secret sharing with $5$ shares and a threshold of $3$. We will pick our secret in the range $0 \ldots 50$ (modulo $50$). I like the number $42$, so we will use that as the secret.

First we will generate a random polynomial of order $3$. This polynomial will be randomly generated, except for the lowest term, where we will fill in our secret ($42$).
My random generator gave me the nice parabola $4x^2 + 25x + 42 \pmod{50}$.
We will take this parabola and evaluate the five points with values of $x$ in the range $1\ldots6$.

[image: Evaluating points on a polynomial]

The exact values of these points are: $(1, 21), (2, 8), (3, 3), (4, 6), (5, 17)$ and $(6, 36)$. We will divide the points under the participants, and we hope they will keep them safe.

> Note that the point $(x,y) = (0,42)$ is off limits, because this would reveal our secret.

## Share combination

We'll say that the participants with the points $(4, 6)$, $(1, 21)$, and $(2, 8)$ want to use their shares to get the original secret back. Recall that we had used a polynomial that was in the form $a_2 x^2 + a_1 x + a_0$. So essentially, we only have to solve the following equation:

$$y = a_2 x^2 + a_1 x + a_0$$

Filling in the three points gives us the following system of linear equations:

$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned} 
a_2 4^2 + a_1 4 + a_0 &=  6 \\ 
a_2 1^2 + a_1 1 + a_0 &= 21 \\ 
a_2 2^2 + a_1 2 + a_0 &=  8 
\end{aligned} 
\right. 
$$

Visualising this in a picture:

[image: Three points describe a polynomial]

Solving this system gives us $a_2 = 4, a_1 = 25, a_0 = 42$, a.k.a. the polynomial $4x^2 + 25x + 42$.

> You may get actually get $4x^2 - 25x + 42$, but remember that the coefficients where defined modulo $50$, so this is equivalent to $4x^2 + 25x + 42$.

The participants remember that they encoded the lowest coefficient $a_0$ as the secret. So now they know that their original secret was $a_0 = \mathbf{42}$:

[image: Filling in x = 0, gives us y = 42.]

Comment: Actually, I would suggest using a line (e.g. a polynomial of order 1), rather than a parabola.  I would expect that "a line can be defined by two points" to be more intuitive to a nonmathematician than "a parabola can be defined by three"

Comment: I was thinking about a thresold $t = 2$, but I tought it would simplify the scheme too much. I could do a line $t=2$, and then stretch by saying "Lagrange interpolation allows us to expand this (...)"?